# Error while opening the web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have been trying to open the web page from the server in command prompt by following the youtube tutorial. But I am getting the following error page in the attempt of opening the web page which has been attached below. Kindly help me out of this. can you guys assist me where the issue is coming.
youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=hE5zeEiVqpw&list=PL55RiY5tL51oGJorjEgl6NVeDbx_fO5jR&index=13

Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

```
    at next (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

I am attaching the error code below:
at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\web\first-1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)

```
if (!view.path) {
      var dirs = Array.isArray(view.root) && view.root.length > 1
        ? 'directories "' + view.root.slice(0, -1).join('", "') + '" or "' + view.root[view.root.length - 1] + '"'
        : 'directory "' + view.root + '"'
      var err = new Error('Failed to lookup view "' + name + '" in views ' + dirs);
```

at C:\Users\web\first-1\app.js:49:7

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im new, but i think its clear that you havent any work to that path node_modules

for node js a server can implemented like this

app.js

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write("<html>");
response.write("<head><title>Node.js</title></head>");
response.write("<body>Hello Web</body>");
response.write("</html>");
response.end();
}).listen(9999);
```

from terminal/cmd

$ path/to/project node app.js

from the browser visit localhost:9999. Enjoy!

Comment: be sure that your nodejs server is installed..by getting a number when typing node -v

Comment: I can able to run server from this method but is it possible to use MongoDB database for the web application without using express in nodejs.

Comment: I have not implement this. But if i had to, i will follow this https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/ references and API

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you assist me to solve this problem.. since it is confusing for me