# trying to include mongodb in my application but facing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

- I have been trying to open the web page from the server in command prompt by following the youtube tutorial.
- But I am getting the following error page in the attempt of opening the web page which has been attached below. Kindly help me out of this.
- can you guys assist me where the issue is coming.
  youtube link:

  res.render('error');
  });

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298599/error-while-opening-the-web-page

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the cause of your problem:

```
res.render('error');
```

As express can't find the view called 'error' in your **views directory**, it's throwing an error.

Comment: thanks for your reply...Can you update in my code it's confusing :(

Comment: I can only replace it with res.send, as Jakub pointed out above. If you want it to show this error page you're talking about, you need to create a view. By the way, your YouTube link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render view with res.render statement, you have to have this view already created in views directory. You can add your view to your views directory, or respond without using any views.

response using plain data:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send('error');
});
```

Still I would recommend you to create view, and use it instead